# Почему не срабатывает свойство border-image-source?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите почему не отрабатывает свойство `border-image-source` ?

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  padding: 15px;
}
.quote {
  max-width: 360px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  color: #fff;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(254.2deg, #B68D98 26.29%, #4B9DFB 82.44%);
  padding: 15px 30px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 130%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вместо border-image-source -> border-image

```
border-image: linear-gradient(254.2deg, #B68D98 26.29%, #4B9DFB 82.44%) 1 round round;
```

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  padding: 15px;
}
.quote {
  max-width: 360px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  color: #fff;
  border-image: linear-gradient(254.2deg, #B68D98 26.29%, #4B9DFB 82.44%) 1 round round;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 130%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
```

Comment: Только `border-radius` почему то нет

Comment: border-radius не работает с border-image, возможно Вам подойдет это решение https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/MqMZGR